# I was struck by lightning

Tags: riddle, wordplay

My story is not a happy one, but I'd like to share it.

> In my early days I sunbathed a lot.
>   I also liked water. And sand.
>   I looked at it through my glasses.
>   I had all the time in the world to watch them all.
>
> Later I used to like spring.
>   It always drove me crazy.
>   I couldn't keep my hands calm.
>   Something dragged me left and right.
>
> Then I got struck by lightning.
>   Not long after that I got my both hands removed.
>   Now I'm still trying to keep my inner light on.
>   The time has come - you'll know it by looking in my eyes.

Who/What Am I?

Hint:

> Every line in the blockquote contains a clue or its part.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Could be a

> Watch/clock

Rationale:

In my early days I sunbathed a lot.

> Broad day/night distinction to tell the time. Or even more likely a sundial as suggested by @Humn

I also liked water.

> Water-clocks?

And sand.

> Hourglass

Later I used to like spring...

> Spring-wound mechanical watches

Something dragged me left and right.

> Pendulum

Then I got struck by lightning.

> Electrically powered watches

Not long after that I got my both hands removed.

> Digital watches

Comment: I think you have it, allow me to add descriptions for some lines?

Comment: @keyurpatel Go ahead!

Comment: @Humn I did consider it but thanks for the comment. Will update my post.

Comment: Yup, this fits well and even the other lines you didn't elaborate on can be seen to match too. That was quick!

Comment: Added some descriptions, I don't understand some lines in the middle, so if you do, edit it :)

Comment: This is of course the correct answer - I'll accept it, but I'd be happy if someone could try to explain the lines you didn't.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL I saw your suggested edits, most of the time I skipped them, but they seemed too substantial. Perhaps (to avoid rejects), you should add a comment saying that you have the permission of both the questioner and the answerer,

Comment: Congratulations. All of your explanations are correct. The rest of the lines are just little hints to get you more on the right way.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a:

> Clock

In my early days I sunbathed a lot.

> Sundials.

I also liked water. And sand.

> Hourglasses and ... water-based clocks.

I looked at it through my glasses.

> Hourglasses again?

I had all the time in the world to watch them all.

> Simply referring to a watch?

Later I used to like spring.

> Springs were used in mechanical clocks.

It always drove me crazy.

> Mechanical clocks were driven.

I couldn't keep my hands calm.
Something dragged me left and right.

> Either referring to a pendulum, or Daylight Savings Time.

Then I got struck by lightning.

> Reference to electrification of clocks.

Not long after that I got my both hands removed.

> Digital clocks.

Now I'm still trying to keep my inner light on.

> Ummmm.... a LED clock's backlight?

The time has come - you'll know it by looking in my eyes.

> Look at a clock to tell the time.

Comment: The same answer (accepted) with the same explanation was given a few hours ago. Please read the other answers before giving a new one.

Comment: I added some new explanations.

Comment: This answer gives a lot of additional explanations so I think it is good we have it.

Answer (score 0):

Addendum for the middle since a pending edit blocks editing the answer:

I couldn't keep my hands calm.

> THe time is always changing and so the hands are moving all the time

Something dragged me left and right.

> Wrong guess: Setting the time via the crown drags the hands left and right Could it be related to Timezones?

Comment: As to keeping my hands calm that is correct. For the second part - it drags me - not my hands. It is actually refering to another type of "me".